# Creating alternative login to Google Users for Google app engine

Tags: python, google-app-engine, model-view-controller, google-cloud-datastore

How does one handle logging in and out/creating users, without using Google Users? I'd like a few more options then just email and password. Is it just a case of making a user model with the fields I need? Is that secure enough?

Alternatively, is there a way to get the user to log in using the Google ID, but without being redirected to the actual Google page?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I recommend using OpenID, see [here](http://googlecode.blogspot.com/2009/07/google-apps-openid-identity-hub-for.html) for more -- just like Stack Overflow does!-)

Comment: Ahh nifty. Thanks for the speedy reply.

Comment: +1 - but you might want to mention session libraries like Beaker that will be necessary for tracking users once they're logged in. There's also simploid, which provides a bit of glue to make OpenID in App Engine easier: http://github.com/Arachnid/simploid/tree/master . I would add my own answer, but you got in first, fair and square. ;)

Comment: For anyone that is interested in simploid, it has moved here: https://github.com/ZedeX/simploid

Answer (score 1):

If you roll your own user model, you're going to need to do your own session handling as well; the App Engine Users API creates login sessions for you behind the scenes.

Also, while this should be obvious, you shouldn't store the user's password in plaintext; store an SHA-1 hash and compare it to a hash of the user's submitted password when they login.

Comment: ...and if you store pwd hashes, don't forget the salt!  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Salt_(cryptography)

Comment: Nah, I was reluctant to use my own model. OpenID sounds the best. Cheers guys